# Split a multiple line text file into a multiple line csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy, split, scikit-learn

I have a text file that contains data in the following form;

```
100157  100157
100157  364207
100157  38848
100157  bradshaw97introduction
100157  bylund99coordinating
100157  dix01metaagent
100157  gray99finding
...
...
```

I'm trying to convert this into a **scikit readable dataset** using the following method:

```
datafile = open(filename.txt, 'r')
data=[]
for row in datafile:
    data.append(row.strip().split('\t'))

c1 = open(filename.csv, 'w')
arr = str(data)
c.write(arr)
c.close
```

However after executing this code, the data gets outputted in a single row whereas I intend to get the data seperated in the csv format neatly in row and columns, like that of the Iris dataset.

Could I get some help as to how I should proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Please show us how the result should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that `scikit readable dataset` is just space separated values with `\n` separating the rows?

If so, quite easy:

Assume you have this file:

```
100157  100157
100157  364207
100157  38848
100157  bradshaw97introduction
100157  bylund99coordinating
100157  dix01metaagent
100157  gray99finding
```

Separated by tabs.

You can easily turn that into space separated new line delimited values:

```
with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r') as fin, open('/tmp/test.out', 'w') as fout:
    data=[row.strip().split('\t') for row in fin]
    st='\n'.join(' '.join(e) for e in data)
    fout.write(st)

print data  
# [['100157', '100157'], ['100157', '364207'], ['100157', '38848'], ['100157', 'bradshaw97introduction'], ['100157', 'bylund99coordinating'], ['100157', 'dix01metaagent'], ['100157', 'gray99finding']]
print st   
100157 100157
100157 364207
100157 38848
100157 bradshaw97introduction
100157 bylund99coordinating
100157 dix01metaagent
100157 gray99finding
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f, open('filename.csv', 'w') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    writer.writerows(line.rstrip().split('\t') for line in f)
```

output csv file:

```
100157,100157
100157,364207
100157,38848
100157,bradshaw97introduction
100157,bylund99coordinating
100157,dix01metaagent
100157,gray99finding
...
```

Comment: That was quick!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @falsetru wouldn't `line.split()` be sufficient?

Comment: @cdhagmann, If there's no space in the data, it's okay. But if there's space, it will split in wrong place.